# How to remove duplicates from a list which might contain lists in Racket

Tags: list, scheme, racket

The code I've written:

```
 (define (make-list lst)
  (cond [(null? lst) '()]
        [(member (car lst) (cdr lst)) (make-list (cdr L))]
        [else (cons (car lst) (duplicates (cdr lst)))]))
```

I want `(make-list '(a (a b b (c b) 3) 5 5.0 (e s) (s e s)))))` to return:

`(a (a  b (c b) 3) 5 (e s))`

But my procedure returns

```
'((a b b (c b) 3) 5 5.0 (e s) (s e s))
```

So it doesn't really do anything besides removing the first element, it doesn't go into the nested lists.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `duplicates` and `L` are forgotten rename mistakes. `make-list` isn't really a good name since it is a well known procedure in the list library of R7RS, originally from SRFI-1 List library. `remove-duplicates` might be a better fit?

```
(define (remove-duplicates lst)
  (cond [(null? lst) '()]
        [(member (car lst) (cdr lst))
         (remove-duplicates (cdr lst))]
        [else
         (cons (car lst) (remove-duplicates (cdr lst)))]))
```

Now this does all the elements in the given list and it only concerns itself with the top level list. sub lists are compared too:

```
(remove-duplicates '(a (b c) (b c) a))
; ==> ((b c) a)
```

You need to instead of just making a list with the first element also check if the first element is a list and do `remove-duplicates` on both parts. Thus you need to do add a term like this:

```
(define (remove-duplicates lst)
  (cond [(null? lst) '()]
        [(member (car lst) (cdr lst))
         (remove-duplicates (cdr lst))]
        [(list? (car lst)) ; or pair?
         (cons (remove-duplicates (car lst)) 
               (remove-duplicates (cdr lst)))]         
        [else
         (cons (car lst)
               (remove-duplicates (cdr lst)))]))

(remove-duplicates '((a b b a) (a b b a)))
; ==> ((b a))
```

Comment: What do you mean by both parts? Both car and cdr of the list?

Comment: @bullebullebagarn Yes. Both `car` and `cdr`. There is also a corner case. Eg `((a b b a) (a b b a))` will become `((b a))` since the term with `member` is before `list?`. If you switch them you get `((b a) (b a))`.

Comment: Hmm I've not been able to solve it.
I added `(cons (remove-duplicates (car lst)) (remove-duplicates (cdr lst)))` when checking if `(car lst)` is a list. But it didn't solve it

Comment: @bullebullebagarn `5` and `5.0` is not the same in the same manner as `"a"` is different from `'a` and `#\a`. You probably need your own `my-equal?` that is looser than `equal?` and use that in `remove-duplicates` Also to remove duplicates in the result and not the source you need two passes.